# Bibtex sorting: Why this behavior?

Tags: bibtex

I am having trouble understanding why bibtex is sorting the following references that way it is.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Four citations: \cite{one,two,three,four}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

...with the following bib.bib file:

```
@inproceedings{one,
  author    = {Author Name},
  title     = {BBB title},
  booktitle = {BBB Conference},
  year      = {2014}
}

@article{two,
  author    = {Author Name},
  title     = {BBB title},
  journal   = {Journal of Journals},
  volume    = {1},
  year      = {2013}
}

@inproceedings{three,
  author    = {Author Name},
  title     = {AAA title},
  booktitle = {AAA Conference},
  year      = {2014}
}

@article{four,
  author    = {Author Name},
  title     = {AAA title},
  journal   = {Journal of Journals},
  volume    = {1},
  year      = {2014}
}
```

It appears that bibtex is sorting by "year" before sorting by "title".  However, according to Section 3.1.2.1 of the [bibtex documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), the default sorting behavoir is to consider "title" before "year".

### Question:

In this MWE, why does bibtex sort by "year" before "title" if the default behavior is to sort by "title" before "year"?

Comment: You linked to `biblatex`, not `bibtex`

Comment: The `plain` style sorting is `author, year, title, as stated in the `bibtex` documentation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the documentation of `bibtex`, the sort order of `plain` is `author, year, title`, as the OP stated, not `author, title, year`. This seems to be a misunderstanding.

[image]

This refers to **plain standard style**, where as in section 2.2 of `bibtex` manual the changes are described:

[image]

If the `author, title, year` sorting is requested, it's perhaps better to use the `biblatex` package with the `sorting=nty` option. (n = name (of author(s)))

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=nty,sortcites=true]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
Four citations: \cite{one,two,three,four}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

With `sorting=nty`, one obtains

[image]

whereas `sorting=nyt` yields the default `plain` style by `bibtex`

[image]

Please compare the two outputs. The result is the same if `backend=biber` 
is used instead of `bibtex`

Comment: The `sortcites=true` is just for convenience and has nothing to do with the sorting of entries in the bibliography

Comment: Thanks! I will switch to using `biblatex` as you suggest. Now I have to figure out what new style I want to use.

Comment: @TysonWilliams: Yes, the styles are quite confusing, somehow. The `biblatex` manual is very elaborate

Answer (score 4):

Christian Hupfer's solution, which uses [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), is elegant and simple. Just in case you can't use biblatex -- say, because you must use a BibTeX-based bibliography style for which no good equivalent exists in biblatex, or because the journal you're submitting your paper to *requires* the use of BibTeX -- here's a way to achieve author-title-year sorting via BibTeX's own mechanisms.

First, create a macro named `\noop` ("no operations") and place it at the top of the bib file, like this:

```
@preamble{ "\newcommand{\noop}[1]{} " }
```

You may be wondering what the point of a macro may be that does absolutely nothing with its argument -- do read on.

Second, prefix the contents of the year fields with `\noop` instructions:

```
@inproceedings{one,
  author    = {Author Name},
  ...
  year      = {\noop{9001}2014}
}

@article{two,
  author    = {Author Name},
  ...
  year      = {\noop{9002}2013}
}

@inproceedings{three,
  author    = {Author Name},
  ...
  year      = {\noop{9003}2014}
}

@article{four,
  author    = {Author Name},
  ...
  year      = {\noop{9004}2014}
}
```

The arguments of the four `\noop` instructions don't have to be consecutive integers, but it's probably easiest to keep track of them if you do use consecutive integers. Note that I suggest using a  range of integers that clearly can't be mistaken for years of publication.

Why does this work? It's important to remember the division of labor between BibTeX and LaTeX: BibTeX assembles the bibliography (and does the sorting of the entries), but LaTeX does the actual typesetting. During the BibTeX run, the `noop{` and `}` parts are removed *during the sorting step*, leaving BibTeX to think that it's dealing with four entries with year fields with the following values: `90012014`, `90022013`, `90032014`, and `90042014`, and BibTeX will sort the entries in that order. If you look closely at the `.bbl` file (which is where BibTeX places its output), you'll see things like `\noop{9001}2014`, etc. Finally, when LaTeX does its typesetting thing, the arguments of the `\noop` instructions are discarded, i.e., only `2014` is typeset, and all is well.

Comment: Thanks for this extra solution. Never encountered this so far (+1)